# AWS Route 53 to ALB managed by AWS Load Balancer Controller

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

I have a domain for my new application, lets call it: app.example.com. Thats a domain registered outside my AWS account.

The application is running on AWS EKS:

- Two Deployments
- Two Services
- One Ingress

Quite simple I guess. Those pods are running on Fargate, so I managed to configure the AWS Load Balancer controller who creates an Application Load Balancer when an Ingress is created.
Then, there is also an external-dns pod configured pointing to a hosted zone on Route 53 (example.com).

Now, each time an Ingress is re-deployed, AWS LBC re-creates the ALB with a different DNS domain, and external-dns is adding records on the hosted zone like:
[image: Route 53 hosted zone record]

If I go to the ALB DNS, the application can be reached, but if I go from the domain app.example.com it can´t.
In a close future, my idea is to use a Blue/Green deployment and that will change the DNS of the ALB, so I have to think of a solution having into account the next step.

Maybe it´s something about the external domain, I mean, AWS is not hosting the domain but I might need some kind of permission or even configure the domain from the other page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, what I was missing is reading in depth the documentation of AWS. Route 53 provides a set of Name Servers for hosted zones. On the external registrar, I had to create NS records pointing to the NS of AWS.
More info:

[SafeNames](https://www.safenames.net/resources/faq)

[1and1](https://www.ionos.es/ayuda/dominios/configurar-y-administrar-un-dominio-externo-en-11-ionos/seleccion-de-los-servidores-dns-para-dominios-externos/)

[GoDaddy](https://es.godaddy.com/help/change-nameservers-for-my-domains-664)

[AWS Wiki - Step 7](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/migrate-dns-domain-in-use.html#migrate-dns-change-name-servers-with-provider)